# Can you find the name for Windows Phone Calendar?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, calendar

I am using [this](https://calendarcontrolwp7.codeplex.com) windows phone calendar control.
The calendar was created in that link because there weren't any controls at the time.
Well my problem is I am to the point where I need to use the selected date from what the user picked in the calendar.  This may be a silly question but I can not find the name of the calendar that was in the code.  In order to find the selected date of the user I need the name of the calendar and because it was a created one there isn't a name for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the calender control in you xaml and set the name property

`<Calender Name="MyCalender"/>`

Now you can access it by name MyCalender

Comment: Ok but when I put that in xaml it comes up with an error saying The name "Calendar" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".  Sorry if these seem like basic questions I'm just starting out and learning.

Comment: if you are new to wp7 then please search for "Telerik Calender control" it is very easy to integrate.1 add dll into project,2.add reference of that dll,3.add namespace in xaml,4finally add the control in xaml

Comment: Well I have already put in a lot of work for this calendar so far and don't really want to start with a new one even though it is easier. So is there a reason why I can't name this current calendar that I am using and why it gives that error?

Comment: because you are not including namespace like this
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" in xaml and after including namespace in xaml you should add calender same as we incudle controls of toolkit like this
<toolkit:Calender name=""/>